# Using rsyslogd with imrelp in Ubuntu?

Tags: 14.04, server, rsyslog

I'm trying to make use of [imrelp](http://www.rsyslog.com/doc/imrelp.html) in Ubuntu 14.04. However, when I check using `lsof -i` or `netstat -autp` nothing listens on the configured port.

Package `librelp0` is installed.

What am I doing wrong?

**NB:** both imudp and imtcp on port 514 work just fine. So please don't suggest to switch to that, that would merely be dodging the issue at hand. The very reason I want to use imrelp is because RELP is supposed to avoid loss of messages:

> From the user's point of view, imrelp works much like imtcp or imgssapi, except that no message loss can occur.

---

Relevant `/etc/rsyslog.conf` stanzas:

```
$ModLoad imuxsock # provides support for local system logging
$ModLoad imklog   # provides kernel logging support
#$ModLoad immark  # provides --MARK-- message capability

# provides UDP syslog reception
#$ModLoad imudp
#$UDPServerRun 514

# provides TCP syslog reception
#$ModLoad imtcp
#$InputTCPServerRun 514

# provides RELP reception
$ModLoad imrelp # needs to be done just once
$InputRELPServerRun 55555
```

I also verified that port 55555 was unused before issuing `service rsyslog restart`.

`/var/log/syslog` shows this when restarting `rsyslogd` (I have upstart debugging enabled):

```
May  5 20:28:38 hostname kernel: [88125.566625] init: Connection from private client
May  5 20:28:38 hostname kernel: [88125.569341] init: Connection from private client
May  5 20:28:38 hostname kernel: [88125.570618] init: rsyslog goal changed from start to stop
May  5 20:28:38 hostname kernel: [88125.570726] init: rsyslog state changed from running to pre-stop
May  5 20:28:38 hostname kernel: [88125.570823] init: rsyslog state changed from pre-stop to stopping
May  5 20:28:38 hostname kernel: [88125.570953] init: Handling stopping event
May  5 20:28:38 hostname rsyslogd: [origin software="rsyslogd" swVersion="7.4.4" x-pid="1212" x-info="http://www.rsyslog.com"] exiting on signal 15.
May  5 20:28:39 hostname rsyslogd: [origin software="rsyslogd" swVersion="7.4.4" x-pid="1249" x-info="http://www.rsyslog.com"] start
May  5 20:28:39 hostname rsyslogd: rsyslogd's groupid changed to 113
May  5 20:28:39 hostname rsyslogd: rsyslogd's userid changed to 107
May  5 20:28:39 hostname kernel: [88125.572594] init: rsyslog main process (1212) exited normally
May  5 20:28:39 hostname kernel: [88125.572666] init: rsyslog state changed from killed to post-stop
May  5 20:28:39 hostname kernel: [88125.572765] init: rsyslog state changed from post-stop to waiting
May  5 20:28:39 hostname kernel: [88125.572982] init: Handling stopped event
May  5 20:28:39 hostname kernel: [88125.573142] init: startpar-bridge (rsyslog--stopped) goal changed from stop to start
May  5 20:28:39 hostname kernel: [88125.573238] init: startpar-bridge (rsyslog--stopped) state changed from waiting to starting
May  5 20:28:39 hostname kernel: [88125.573419] init: Handling starting event
May  5 20:28:39 hostname kernel: [88125.573495] init: startpar-bridge (rsyslog--stopped) state changed from starting to security
May  5 20:28:39 hostname kernel: [88125.573593] init: startpar-bridge (rsyslog--stopped) state changed from security to pre-start
May  5 20:28:39 hostname kernel: [88125.573692] init: startpar-bridge (rsyslog--stopped) state changed from pre-start to spawned
May  5 20:28:39 hostname kernel: [88125.574885] init: startpar-bridge (rsyslog--stopped) main process (1241)
May  5 20:28:39 hostname kernel: [88125.574907] init: startpar-bridge (rsyslog--stopped) state changed from spawned to post-start
May  5 20:28:39 hostname kernel: [88125.575050] init: startpar-bridge (rsyslog--stopped) state changed from post-start to running
May  5 20:28:39 hostname kernel: [88125.575288] init: Handling started event
May  5 20:28:39 hostname kernel: [88125.575787] init: startpar-bridge (rsyslog--stopped) main process (1241) exited normally
May  5 20:28:39 hostname kernel: [88125.575899] init: startpar-bridge (rsyslog--stopped) goal changed from start to stop
May  5 20:28:39 hostname kernel: [88125.576001] init: startpar-bridge (rsyslog--stopped) state changed from running to stopping
May  5 20:28:39 hostname kernel: [88125.576115] init: Handling stopping event
May  5 20:28:39 hostname kernel: [88125.576187] init: startpar-bridge (rsyslog--stopped) state changed from stopping to killed
May  5 20:28:39 hostname kernel: [88125.576285] init: startpar-bridge (rsyslog--stopped) state changed from killed to post-stop
May  5 20:28:39 hostname kernel: [88125.576391] init: startpar-bridge (rsyslog--stopped) state changed from post-stop to waiting
May  5 20:28:39 hostname kernel: [88125.576734] init: Handling stopped event
May  5 20:28:39 hostname kernel: [88125.578591] init: Connection from private client
May  5 20:28:39 hostname kernel: [88125.579494] init: rsyslog goal changed from stop to start
May  5 20:28:39 hostname kernel: [88125.579582] init: rsyslog state changed from waiting to starting
May  5 20:28:39 hostname kernel: [88125.579705] init: Handling starting event
May  5 20:28:39 hostname kernel: [88125.579785] init: rsyslog state changed from starting to security
May  5 20:28:39 hostname kernel: [88125.579881] init: rsyslog state changed from security to pre-start
May  5 20:28:39 hostname kernel: [88125.581088] init: rsyslog pre-start process (1242)
May  5 20:28:39 hostname kernel: [88125.583975] init: Connection from private client
May  5 20:28:39 hostname kernel: [88125.588103] init: rsyslog pre-start process (1242) exited normally
May  5 20:28:39 hostname kernel: [88125.588172] init: rsyslog state changed from pre-start to spawned
May  5 20:28:39 hostname kernel: [88125.589433] init: rsyslog main process (1248)
May  5 20:28:39 hostname kernel: [88125.590290] init: rsyslog main process (1248) executable changed
May  5 20:28:39 hostname kernel: [88125.593495] init: rsyslog main process (1248) became new process (1249)
May  5 20:28:39 hostname kernel: [88125.593525] init: rsyslog state changed from spawned to post-start
May  5 20:28:39 hostname kernel: [88125.593729] init: rsyslog state changed from post-start to running
May  5 20:28:39 hostname kernel: [88125.593918] init: Handling started event
May  5 20:28:39 hostname kernel: [88125.594192] init: startpar-bridge (rsyslog--started) goal changed from stop to start
May  5 20:28:39 hostname kernel: [88125.594355] init: startpar-bridge (rsyslog--started) state changed from waiting to starting
May  5 20:28:39 hostname kernel: [88125.594705] init: Handling starting event
May  5 20:28:39 hostname kernel: [88125.594813] init: startpar-bridge (rsyslog--started) state changed from starting to security
May  5 20:28:39 hostname kernel: [88125.594949] init: startpar-bridge (rsyslog--started) state changed from security to pre-start
May  5 20:28:39 hostname kernel: [88125.595128] init: startpar-bridge (rsyslog--started) state changed from pre-start to spawned
May  5 20:28:39 hostname kernel: [88125.596402] init: startpar-bridge (rsyslog--started) main process (1254)
May  5 20:28:39 hostname kernel: [88125.596426] init: startpar-bridge (rsyslog--started) state changed from spawned to post-start
May  5 20:28:39 hostname kernel: [88125.596614] init: startpar-bridge (rsyslog--started) state changed from post-start to running
May  5 20:28:39 hostname kernel: [88125.596918] init: Handling started event
May  5 20:28:39 hostname kernel: [88125.597463] init: startpar-bridge (rsyslog--started) main process (1254) exited normally
May  5 20:28:39 hostname kernel: [88125.597533] init: startpar-bridge (rsyslog--started) goal changed from start to stop
May  5 20:28:39 hostname kernel: [88125.597674] init: startpar-bridge (rsyslog--started) state changed from running to stopping
May  5 20:28:39 hostname kernel: [88125.597814] init: Handling stopping event
May  5 20:28:39 hostname kernel: [88125.597884] init: startpar-bridge (rsyslog--started) state changed from stopping to killed
May  5 20:28:39 hostname kernel: [88125.598018] init: startpar-bridge (rsyslog--started) state changed from killed to post-stop
May  5 20:28:39 hostname kernel: [88125.598120] init: startpar-bridge (rsyslog--started) state changed from post-stop to waiting
May  5 20:28:39 hostname kernel: [88125.598472] init: Handling stopped event
```

The files `auth.log`, `dmesg` and `kern.log` contain nothing related to restarting `rsyslogd`.

Answer (score 0):

You can find the package rsyslog-relp in the repos. I believe that will be helpful in providing the module you need.